# Correct way to start single activity from card scroller

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have created a glass app in which I have CardScrollActivity that uses CardScroller and navigate to other Activities from it like below :

```
public class CardScrollActivity extends Activity {

private List<CardBuilder> mCards;
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;
private ExampleCardScrollAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();

    setupClickListener();


    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

   private void setupClickListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      mCardScrollView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              log(" onitemclick called "  );

              if(id == 0)
              {
                  log(" onitemclick called and select 1 item "  );

                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                            Main2Activity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
              }

              if(id == 1)
              {
                  log(" onitemclick called and select 2 item "  );
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            CompassActivity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
              }

              if(id == 2)
              {
                  log(" onitemclick called and select 3 item "  );
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            GpsActivity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
              }
          }
      });

}
```

Now , the problem is that when I select any item from Cardscroller then stack trace shows starting the activity multiple times not once , why is it selecting multiple times plz help ?

Comment: Could you add the `logcat` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, without you providing your LogCat error, there isn't much I can do to help.

The only thing I can say is that maybe you could try finishing your current activity to make sure it isn't doing anything weird after you launch a new one. For that, you need to add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to your intent, then call `finish()` right after you launch the intent.

For one intent call, it would look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Here's the implementation for you:

```
if(id == 0) {
    log(" onitemclick called and select 1 item "  );
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); 
} else if(id == 1) {
    log(" onitemclick called and select 2 item "  );
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CompassActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); 
} else if(id == 2) {
    log(" onitemclick called and select 3 item "  );
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GpsActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); 
}
```